# How are changes populated to FrontEnd in Microservices Event First scenario?

Tags: asp.net, microservices, angularjs, eventual-consistency

I've been reading recently about Event First approach to microservices where Event Store is a Single Source of Truth for all the applications (https://dzone.com/articles/data-consistency-in-microservices-architecture).

[image]

This is very different from Change First approach were we:

1. Save item to microservice database (in this scenario that database would be the source of truth)
2. On success we send event with change to Event Stream

The Event First approach seems really interesting but there is one thing that's nagging me. How should the change be populated on the front end ?

**EDIT**

Scenario:

1. We create a new user on the UI. The change is send to BackEnd.
2. BackEnd writes the change to EventStore and subscribes to it but the change is not yet populated in its database. Request is returned to client.
3. Asynchronously BackEnd tries to add user based on its subscription but it fails.
4. On the UI user tries to edit the newly created record. Sends update request to backend. Should we at this point rely on the local database to check if the record exists and return an error ? We have inconsistency at this point and user will know about it but isn't it too late ? Or maybe this scenario is incorrect at some point.

Regards.

Comment: Websockets, or SignalR, or whatever other mechanism you choose to employ.

Comment: **Thought experiment:** What if you did things the usual way, but instead of your UI getting JSON from a service that interrogates the database, it gets the JSON from your event store or some caching mechanism?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes but what other mechanism would that be :) ? WebSockets were the only approach I could think of.

Comment: Why do you think you need Websockets?

Comment: Actually thinking about it I was proposing WebSokects because then I would be able to return Id back to client. I don't have it when the record isn't actually written to the database. Also assuming that the operation failed when writing to Event Store I wouldn't see the record on the UI yet. Would relying on the natural keys and showing record on the UI even though it failed being saved to Event Store the correct approach in this scenario ?

Comment: Assuming you only consider Event Store records that had succeeded, wouldn't it be just as easy to obtain the JSON data that drives your UI from the Event Store as it is to get it from the database?

Comment: You're asking the wrong guy about what is "correct."  I don't use what is "correct;" I don't believe that exists, and if it does, it will change five years or five minutes from now.

Comment: Now, if your question is "how do I update my UI *in real-time* if the status of my data changes," then yeah, you need something like websockets.

Comment: Thanks for all the anserws :) Let me give you an example. What if my UI/BackEnd relies on surrogate keys ( identity ID). For example for the Update operations. This was the standard approach until now. If I'd use Event Store the only place I could get it from is the local microservices database. So correct me if I'm wrong but then I would have to use natural keys. That would be the change required to use Event First approach and not to use WebSockets (WebSockets would populate my UI when the Subscribe operation finishes so there I could get an ID)

Comment: wait when you say surrogate key, do you mean generated by the database?

Comment: You don't need a database to get surrogate keys.  But yeah, now we're getting somewhere.  Edit your question to focus specifically on the surrogate keys problem.  And no, switching to natural keys is not the way to go.

Comment: stop doing that and embrace GUIDs